# Disable <script> in debugger mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm a SQL programmer that years ago used to write .NET desktop apps, so of course, I now get to maintain the company websites.  I inherited a website that in production executes pixel code all over the place. When I'm testing, I'd prefer not to execute these functions so I don't skew the tracking by the 3rd party marketing department (or let them find out how many times it took me to get my code change to work, let's be honest...). Is there to way to disable this script, just say "nope" when I'm in the IDE?

I've traced all the functions I want to disable back to this one in the _layout.cshtml view.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '<PixelID>');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<PixelID>&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

If needed, here is one of calls to this function.

```
<!-- Facebook ViewContent pixel code col-->
<script>
    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
        content_ids: ['@Model.Collection.Sku'],
        content_type: 'product',
        value: @Model.Collection.Price,
        currency: 'USD'
    });
</script>
<!-- End facebook ViewContent pixel code -->
```

Isn't there a way to say "if debugging ==-1 {don't execute this}? What parameter would I use and where would it go?

Comment: Depends on what tools you are using, but the simplest one: comment it out.

Comment: `#if !DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif`

Comment: Using VS 2017. If I comment out this, I have to remember to uncomment it when I promote changes.  Isn't there a way to say "If debugging == -1 { don't execute this}? What parameter would I use and where would the code go?

Comment: Updated the question to (hopefully) make it clearer...

Comment: Mary, where would that code go? Should I wrap the <script>...</script> with the #if (replaced "Debug version" with the function? It didn't seem to do anything. Thx.

Comment: You've marked this C#, but C# is a language, not a web UI framework. Are you using ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET Web Forms? UWP?

Comment: Sorry.. This is ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Also, you should theoretically be able to configure the tool (Facebook Pixel) to filter out calls from localhost for debugging purposes.

Comment: Heretic Monkey - I don't have control over the FB Pixel stuff, so I don't know if they have done that or not. I'll send a message to them tomorrow to double-check. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks EdSF! I was able to figure out how to do it from that link.

Answer (score 0):

(Thanks EdSF and everyone)
The setting I was looking for was: this.Context.IsDebuggingEnabled

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
@if (!this.Context.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <text>
            !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
            {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
            n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
            if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
            n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
            t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
            fbq('init', '<PixelID>');
            fbq('track', 'PageView');
        </text>
    }
</script>
<noscript>
@if (!this.Context.IsDebuggingEnabled)
    {
        <text>
            <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
                src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=<PixelID>&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
        </text>
    }
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

On localhost, I get:
    `<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
    </script>
    <noscript>
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->`

And on the server the functions are where they are supposed to be.